# Not able to get a value from yml file in groovy

Tags: groovy, yaml

I have stored an entire yaml file into a `Map yamlConfig` which i am able to print and check.

The Output when I run the code: `yamlConfig.each{ k, v -> println "${k}:${v}" }` is:

```
Host:localhost
Port:10000
application:[name:ABC, preferences:[UUID:d3f3278e, server:localhost:2222]]
services:[[name:XYZ, instances:1, start:true]]
dataSets:[[name:ABC], [name:XYZ]]
```

Now, I am trying to fetch a value from Map using following code:

```
println yamlConfig.get("services").getAt("name")
```

However, I am getting the value: `[XYZ]`. Instead I need the result as `XYZ`, without square brackets.

Yml file I am using:

```
Host: localhost
Port: 10000
application:
  name: ABC
  preferences:
    UUID: d3f3278e
    server: localhost:2222
services:
  - name: XYZ
    instances: 1
    start: true
data:
  - name: ABC
  - name: XYZ
```

Comment: How did you print the map in your first code paste ? Could you show us what `println yamlConfig` outputs ?

Comment: Hi sensei, I have updated the question with the code which I used to print the yamlConfig. The output of `println yamlConfig` is also there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of the `-` character placed before your `name` property. It makes the yaml parser treat what's inside the `services` section as an array.

When you ask for the `name` property doing `yamlConfig['services']['name']` groovy gives you all the macthing properties of array items in the services array, and it can only return them in another array.

So either remove the `-` or use `yamlConfig['services'][0]['name']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
yamlConfig.get("services")
```

return a list but not a service, therefore when you apply getAt to the returned list of services it returns a list of names.

```
yamlConfig.get("services").getAt('name')
```

actually does

```
yaml['services'].collect { it['name'] }
```

so in order to get a name of a certain service you need to do something like this:

```
println yaml['services'][0]['name']
```